# How to change the amount of RAM displayed in System Properties

Tags: windows-xp

I have this product that requires at least 1 GB Physical Memory in order to be installed. 
On my XP Pro machine I have 1 GB of RAM but in System Properties only 0.99 GB of RAM is displayed. The problem is that the product installer checks the memory displayed in System Properties (just a guess, not sure) and cannot continue the setup because it sees only 0.99 GB.

Is there any way to change the displayed memory in the System Properties? Or how can I trick the installer to skip the memory check?

Thanks.

Comment: What product is this?

Comment: It's a call recording software - Retell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why your system displays 0.99GB of RAM is probably because your integrated graphics card is using some of the RAM.

Two recommendations:

1) Upgrade your RAM - it's cheap anyway, and 1GB is somewhat on the thin side nowadays.

2) Unzip your application installer to a folder. There should be a config file that you can edit somewhere to remove the memory check.

Comment: Alternatively you can reduce the amount of RAM the graphic card uses, using BIOS given that reducing your graphic memory will not be a problem again for the setup ;)

Comment: When you have only 1GB, anything that your graphics card use will result in you short of 1GB system memory. :)

Comment: I could not find any config file to edit... I will close the question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it isn't possible to change it, but you can try one of the following instead:

- Some installers have a commandline argument or switch that disables the checks.
- Temporarily add another stick of RAM if you have one.

Comment: Adding another stick of RAM sure fixes the problem.